# AppHarbor compilation error (NuGet)

Tags: nuget, appharbor

Recently my build on AppHarbor was broked with following message:

```
     The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages   in the build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317568.
```

I have next changes related to NuGet (in packages config):

from

```
      <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.1.10" targetFramework="net45" />
```

to

```
     <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.10" targetFramework="net45" />
     <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.13" targetFramework="net45" />
```

+

```
     <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I have reinstalled to old versions Bcl and Net packages,but this doesnt help me.Has anybody the same problem?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Microsoft blog post has additional details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/22/improved-package-restore.aspx). Apparently, checking in your `.targets` file addresses the problem.